# Почему "рассориться" пишется с двумя С?

Tags: орфография

Почему слово "рассориться" пишется с двумя буквами С? Ведь слово "ссора" тоже пишется с двумя "с", а "ссор" это корень, получается, а приставки "ра" не существует, получается должно быть "расссориться", а не "рассориться".

Answer (score 2):

На стыке морфем из трёх согласных пишутся только две.

В справочнике Лопатина читаем:
§  96.

> В слитно пишущихся словах не пишется больше двух одинаковых согласных
>   подряд, хотя бы это и требовалось составом слова, напр.:
>   рассориться (рас+ссориться), колонный (от колонна: колонн+ный), ванная
>   (от ванна: ванн+ная), пятитонный (от тонна: пяти+тонн+ный), одесский
>   (от Одесса: одесс+ский), прусский (от Пруссия: прусс+ский), донбасский
>   (от Донбасс: донбасс+ский). Но ср. сохранение трех  одинаковых
>   согласных в пишущихся через дефис словах: пресс-секретарь,
>   пресс-служба, масс-старт, грамм-молекула, килограмм-метр.

http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=50

Answer (score 2):

1) **Вопрос не новый**, в Сети он уже обсуждался неоднократно, например: http://education.ques.ru/questions/pochemu-slovo-rassoritsya-pishetsya-s-dvumya-s-a-ne-tremya-pristavka-ras-koren-ssor-ot-ssora

2) Ответ на него можно дать очень простой: **в русской графике нет утроенных согласных** (исключением могут быть аббревиатуры, СССР например). Очень проблематично найти **и другие языки,** где есть тройные согласные.

3) Почему? Ответ тоже простой: **такая запись не имеет смысла.** К примеру, в русском языке удвоение согласных позволяет определить морфемный состав слова, в английском языке двойные согласные могут влиять на слогораздел и правильное чтение слов (sun|ny, первый гласный читается по правилу закрытого слога).

4)  В то же время нельзя требовать от правила сохранения морфемного состава **абсолютного соответствия**: морфемный состав сохраняется в общем случае, когда это возможно, **когда это позволяет графика и фонетика.** В других же случаях происходит усечение морфем, наложение их друг на друга и т.д.

**Ярким примером является суффикс СК**, который используется при образовании относительных прилагательных от имен собственных, в этом случае возможны различные варианты:

Одесса  — одесский (усечение С в основе), Омск — омский (полное наложение суффикса), Уэльс — уэльский (частичное наложение суффикса), дамаск — дамасский (усечение К в основе).

Answer (score 1):

Русская письменность во многом опирается на *фонетику* устной речи, в которой по произношению можно различить только *одиночные* и *сдвоенные* согласные звуки (ини-то и записываются соотв. сдвоенными буквами) и нельзя выделить какой-либо "строенный" согласный звук. Поэтому, если по какому-либо орфографическому правилу при словообразовании возникает стечение более двух согласных букв, они количественно редуцируются до двух (не столь важно,  как это трактоватьв вашем случае: как редукцию приставки до "ра-" или просто сокращение количества букв). Этим сохраняется фонетичность записи -  иначе при чтении требовалось бы неестественное (и в результате тщетное) усилие воспроизвести строенный согласный.

Для сравнения: во многих других языках вообще нет связи между количеством согласных букв и длительностью произношения согласного звука; например, в английском сдвоенные буквы могут управлять чтением слога, но не произносятся отлично от одиночного согласного.

Answer (score 0):

> Ведь слово "ссора" тоже пишется с двумя "с", а "ссор" это корень,
>   получается, а приставки "ра" не существует, получается должно быть
>   "расссориться", а не "рассориться".

Вопрос об орфографии при утроении согласных в русском языке не лишен смысла, но пример вы выбрали неудачный. Исторический корень в слове "ссора" - "сор", а первая "с" приставка, которая исчезает при использовании другой приставки "рас". Поэтому причин для трех С подряд тут просто нет. Подобных примеров, где бы могло потребоваться три согласных на стыке приставки и корня, я вообще не знаю.

Но есть другие примеры, где все не так просто, это случаи скопления одинаковых согласных на стыке корня и суффикса. Обычно это происходит с именами собственными и некоторыми заимствованными нарицательными, сохранившими удвоенный согласный а абсолютном конце слова (Лисс, Улисс, флосс, босс, пресс). Прилагательные на "-ский" от таких имен обычно не образуются (или принимают форму "-овский"), но если уж такое прилагательное образовано, то одно С опускается ("улисский", флосский - и т.д.).

Нечто подобное проискодит при попытке приставить к слову на -нн (джинн, банн, финн) суффикс "-ник". Встречается, например, упоминание волшебного атрибута для вызова джинна, который назван "джинником", но не "джиннником". И это правильно, тут языковое чутьё создателей этой игрушки не обмануло.

Другими словами, русская орфография не допускает боле двух одинаковых согласных подряд. Такие образования крайне редки в русском языке, поэтому правило это введено скорее для общности, чем для актуального использования.